# issue with affix-bottom in windows10 internet explorer 15 version

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap 3 and class affix is working in all OS and versions, but coming to windows 10, internet explorer 15 version `class=affix` and `affix-top` is working fine but `affix-bottom` is changing from affix to `affix-bottom`.

But in other OS and browsers it's working fine.
this is Js:

```
$(".my-affix-div").affix({
   offset: {
   top: 440,
   bottom: 270
 }
```

this is Css:

```
.affix{
 top:60px;
}
.affix-bottom {
 bottom:270px;
 position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update ur bootstrap version or simply download bootstrap3.3.7v and you will find affix.js file in js folder. add it to ur project and code as well.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin toggles this behaviour on and off (changes the value of CSS position from static to fixed), depending on scroll position.

I am testing on Internet Explorer 10

Try Link

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_scrollspy_affix2&stacked=h

Comment: please check this you can get clarity.. as iam new to bootstrap please explain briefly